# How to do InOrder traversal with B-Tree?

Tags: c++, b-tree

```
struct BTreeNode {
    bool is_leaf=true;
    std::vector<int> elements;
    std::vector<BTreeNode*> children;
    BTreeNode() {}
    BTreeNode (std::vector<int> v) {
    this->elements = v;
    }
};

void traverse(BTreeNode* root) {
  for(int i = 0; i < (int)root->children.size(); ++i){
    traverse(root->children[i]);
    cout << root->elements[i] << endl;
  }
  traverse(root->children[root->children.size() -1]);
}
```

My method somehow segfaults. How do we write a correct inOrder Traversal for B-Tree?

Comment: Two traverses should be identical: traverse(root->children[i]). And don't forget to check if root "is_leaf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the last traverse call when you are at a leaf.  I don't think that this traverse is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming BTreeNode is a generic definition of your b-tree node, whereas T1 is the type of the keys and T2 is the type of the values in the tree, and sortedKeys is the list you are after, you can use the following recursive method. The idea is very similar to an inOrder traversal in binary search tree, first visit the left-most child, then visit the key- then continue, Since the number of children in B-tree is always one bigger than the number of keys, a check is needed before visiting the key [code is in c#, but can easily be converted to any other language, the purpose is to show the algorithm only].

```
public void InOrderTraversal(BTreeNode<T1, T2> node, List<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>> sortedKeys)
        {
            if (node != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < node.Children.Count; i++)
                {
                    InOrderTraversal(node.Children[i], sortedKeys);
                    if (i < node.KeyValues.Count)
                        sortedKeys.Add(node.KeyValues[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```